# Indesign GREP: Negative lookbehind with variable length

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I use a complex .txt for the basic findchangebylist-script that is included in inDesign to fix some common typography mistakes. F.e. it changes the hyphen to an en dash and puts a thinspace between *3-4* or puts a fixed space between *p.4* (page four). Sadly this destroys URLs if they contain these. For exhample `http://www.file3-4p.4fire.com` becomes `http://www.file3 - 4p. 4fire.com`.

Is there anyway to exclude anything that is preceded by **http**? As I understand, there is no negative lookbehind with variable length like it exists for the positive lookbehind with \K. But does anyone know a workaround for this?

My grep for these exhamples is like this:

```
grep    {findWhat:"([0-9]\\.?)\\s?[~=-]\\s?([0-9])"}    {changeTo:"$1~|~=~|$2"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false} 
grep    {findWhat:"(p\\.)\\s?([0-9])"}  {changeTo:"$1~s$2"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false}
```

Comment: I *think* that's doable but I would also find a way to define the end boundary (.com ). Are all of your URLs ending with .com or a break of some sort?

Comment: No, they are always ending with some variable. They are mostly (but not always) dois like this https://doi.org/10.1037/0003-066X.55.11.1196 . Sometimes they end with a number, sometimes with a letter or other character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all your text is black, you could first apply some other color to URLs, then perform the GREP find/change to all black text and finally change the color of URLs back to black.

Create a color swatch which you *only* use for temporarily coloring the URLs. Here I call it `temp url`.

First we select URLs with `http(s)?://[^\s\r]+(?=\s|\r|)`. This should work with URLs followed by a white space or a paragraph break or positioned at the end of a story. You can tweak this to fit your needs. In the `changeProperties` object we set `fillColor` to the name of the temporary swatch for URLs: `temp url`.

```
grep    {findWhat:"http(s)?://[^\\s\\r]+(?=\\s|\\r|)"}  {fillColor:"temp url"}  {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false}
```

Then follows whatever changes you want to make. In the `findProperties` object of each search we set `fillColor` to `Black` to only apply changes to black text.

```
grep    {findWhat:"([0-9]\\.?)\\s?[~=-]\\s?([0-9])", fillColor:"Black"} {changeTo:"$1~|~=~|$2"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false} 
grep    {findWhat:"(p\\.)\\s?([0-9])", fillColor:"Black"}   {changeTo:"$1~s$2"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false}
```

Finally we change the color of URLs back. In the `findProperties` object we set `fillColor` to `temp url` and in the `changeProperties` we set `fillColor` to `Black`.

```
grep    {fillColor:"temp url"}  {fillColor:"Black"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false}
```

### Further automatization

Instead of manually adding the temporary swatch for the URLs, it's possible to add it within the `FindChangeByList.jsx` script. I would copy the script and the `FindChangeSupport` folder to the folder with user scripts first though.

Locate the line in the beginning of the script that looks like this:

```
main();
```

And change it to this:

```
var swatch = app.activeDocument.swatches.item("Black").duplicate();
swatch.name = "temp url";
main();
swatch.remove();
```

This will make a duplicate of the Black swatch, name it `temp url`, run the `main` function and in the end remove the `temp url` swatch again.

Comment: That sounds promising but apart from some minor differences which I might be able to solve, i can't seem the grab the standard [black] (which is [schwarz] in my indesign). It works with any other new color but not with the standard one. Is there a way to grap that? Is it also possible to create the temp url color via the txt or maybe by editing the jsx?

Comment: I was fearing you might get trouble with that . And you have of course tried both "schwarz" and "Schwarz"? But yes, you could do it within the jsx and thereby eliminating the need for the custom swatch I think. It's just way more complicated to explain. But that wouldn't solve the problem with not being able to search only within [Black] text, would it? You have to find out how to select it in the German version.

Comment: I managed it to work, for some reason I wrote "Black" in small letters so that was the problem. Thank you. I put in everything you wrote and it works wonderfully. (I used (http(s)?://[^ ]+(?=\r))|(http(s)?://[^ ]+(?= )) to include the URLs at the end of a paragraph.) Now I need to find a way to create this temporary color without needing to resort to do it manually.

Comment: Ah, you can create the swatch in the `.jsx` file with some name, then refer to that name in the `.txt` and afterwards delete it again. I might add this to the answer later.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to figure out how. I managed to add a color but still need to figure out how to not make it fail if the color name already exists (if the script is used a second time it fails.) Sadly my scripting knowledge ist barely existend. 
What does work for me though, is to use an existing color we already have in our templates and use the GREP for the URL again to switch it to black again. But I still want to find out how to do it your way.

Comment: You need to delete the swatch again in the script after performing the grep searches. So the script cleans up after itself. Also need to use an obscure name which you are certain you will never use in a document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126562/discussion-between-wolff-and-sabiner).